# SMTP doesnt allow me to login (dovecot postfix SSL)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix, smtp, dovecot

So i followed an tutorial to setup a mailserver but sadly SMTP doesnt seem to work. It also doesn't show any errors in /var/log/mail.log or /var/log/dovecot.log.

Seems like im the only one that has this problem since i cant find a solution that solves my problem.

```
telnet DOMAIN 587
220 mail.DOMAIN ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo DOMAIN
250-mail.DOMAIN
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

I assume its due the AUTH missing in the EHLO. It probably is something small that i have missed. But sadly i do not know what or where to look.

Postfix configuration:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/dovecot.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.DOMAIN
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, DOMAIN, mail.DOMAIN, localhost.DOMAIN, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

Postfix master.conf

```
submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -v -o 
syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Mail.log with smtpd -v (data anonimalized)

```
Dec 25 00:57:49 vps2 postfix/master[16140]: daemon started -- version 3.1.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/smtpd[16149]: name_mask: all
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/smtpd[16149]: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv4 addresses
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/smtpd[16149]: inet_addr_local: configured 3 IPv6 addresses
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: process generation: 4 (4)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions ~? debug_peer_list
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions ~? fast_flush_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions ~? mynetworks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions ~? permit_mx_backup_networks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions ~? qmqpd_authorized_clients
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions ~? relay_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions ~? smtpd_access_maps
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: mynetworks ~? debug_peer_list
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: mynetworks ~? fast_flush_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: mynetworks ~? mynetworks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: name_mask: host
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: been_here: 127.0.0.1/32: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: been_here: MY_SERVER_IP/32: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: been_here: [::1]/128: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: been_here: [2a01:7c8:aac3:142:5054:ff:fe30:a509]/128: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: been_here: [fe80::5054:ff:fe30:a509]/128: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: mynetworks_core: 127.0.0.1/32 MY_SERVER_IP/32 [::1]/128 [2a01:7c8:aac3:142:5054:ff:fe30:a509]/128 [fe80::5054:ff:fe30:a509]/128
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: mynetworks ~? debug_peer_list
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: mynetworks ~? fast_flush_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: mynetworks ~? mynetworks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: relay_domains ~? debug_peer_list
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: relay_domains ~? fast_flush_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: relay_domains ~? mynetworks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: relay_domains ~? permit_mx_backup_networks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: relay_domains ~? qmqpd_authorized_clients
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: relay_domains ~? relay_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: permit_mx_backup_networks ~? debug_peer_list
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: permit_mx_backup_networks ~? fast_flush_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: permit_mx_backup_networks ~? mynetworks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: permit_mx_backup_networks ~? permit_mx_backup_networks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: connect to subsystem private/proxymap
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr request = open
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr table = unix:passwd.byname
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr flags = 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: flags
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: flags
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 16
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: (end)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: dict_proxy_open: connect to map=unix:passwd.byname status=0 server_flags=fixed
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: dict_open: proxy:unix:passwd.byname
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: Compiled against Berkeley DB: 5.3.28?
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: Run-time linked against Berkeley DB: 5.3.28?
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: warning: database /etc/aliases.db is older than source file /etc/aliases
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: dict_open: hash:/etc/aliases
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: user = postfix
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: password = MY_PASSWORD
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: dbname = MY_DATABASE
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: result_format = %s
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: option_file = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: option_group = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: tls_key_file = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: tls_cert_file = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: tls_CAfile = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: tls_CApath = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: tls_ciphers = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_bool: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: tls_verify_cert = on
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_int: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: expansion_limit = 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: query = SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s'
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: domain =
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: hosts = localhost
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: dict_open: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: user = postfix
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: password = MY_PASSWORD
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: dbname = MY_DATABASE
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: result_format = %s
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: option_file = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: option_group = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: tls_key_file = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: tls_cert_file = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: tls_CAfile = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: tls_CApath = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: tls_ciphers = <NULL>
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_bool: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: tls_verify_cert = on
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_int: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: expansion_limit = 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: domain =
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: cfg_get_str: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: hosts = localhost
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: dict_open: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_access_maps ~? debug_peer_list
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_access_maps ~? fast_flush_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_access_maps ~? mynetworks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_access_maps ~? permit_mx_backup_networks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_access_maps ~? qmqpd_authorized_clients
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_access_maps ~? relay_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: smtpd_access_maps ~? smtpd_access_maps
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: unknown_helo_hostname_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: unknown_address_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: unverified_recipient_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: unverified_sender_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: name_mask: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: auto_clnt_create: transport=local endpoint=private/tlsmgr
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/tlsmgr
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr request = seed
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr size = 32
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: seed
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: seed
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: E8YwzeOEqKCuW953KHc29HvPP6/crEMhAg9Nz5Uy/js=
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: (end)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr request = policy
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr cache_type = smtpd
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: cachable
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: cachable
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: timeout
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: timeout
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 3600
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: (end)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: fast_flush_domains ~? debug_peer_list
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: parent_domain_matches_subdomains: fast_flush_domains ~? fast_flush_domains
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: name_mask: no_header_body_checks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: name_mask: no_unknown_recipient_checks
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: name_mask: no_milters
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: auto_clnt_create: transport=local endpoint=private/anvil
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: connection established
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: master_notify: status 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: name_mask: resource
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: name_mask: software
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: connect from cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: 255.255.255.255: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: 255.255.255.255: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 255.255.255.255 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 255.255.255.255 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl ~? [::1]/128
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 255.255.255.255 ~? [::1]/128
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: 255.255.255.255: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/anvil
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr request = connect
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr ident = submission:255.255.255.255
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: count
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: count
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 1
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: rate
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 1
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: (end)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: > cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]: 220 mail.DOMAIN ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: < cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]: ????g?
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: smtpd_forbidden_commands: ????g? ~? connect
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: smtpd_forbidden_commands: ????g? ~? get
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: smtpd_forbidden_commands: ????g? ~? post
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: ????g?: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: > cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: < cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]: ??????
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: smtpd_forbidden_commands: ? ~? connect
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: smtpd_forbidden_commands: ? ~? get
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_string: smtpd_forbidden_commands: ? ~? post
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: ?: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: > cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: < cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]:
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: > cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]: 500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: < cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]:
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: > cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]: 500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: smtp_get: EOF
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 255.255.255.255 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 255.255.255.255 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl ~? [::1]/128
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 255.255.255.255 ~? [::1]/128
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: match_list_match: 255.255.255.255: no match
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr request = disconnect
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: send attr ident = submission:255.255.255.255
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: status
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute value: 0
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: input attribute name: (end)
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255]
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: disconnect from cm-4-1d.dynamic.ziggo.nl[255.255.255.255] unknown=0/2 commands=0/2
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: master_notify: status 1
Dec 25 00:57:52 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: connection closed
Dec 25 00:57:57 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: proxymap stream disconnect
Dec 25 00:57:57 vps2 postfix/submission/smtpd[16149]: auto_clnt_close: disconnect private/tlsmgr stream
```

Link to the tutorial i followed:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin

If you require more information please ask me.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal you cannot login into cleartext SMTP as you have provided the following option:

```
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

You can try to connect using starttls with the openssl client:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect DOMAIN:587
```

You should then have access to the AUTH command.